# Microsoft SSAS how to retain default row names?

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

Need help on ssas. I am so newbie with this thing. :)
I have this 2 dimension in my cube product_sales and salesgroup

this is the cube
 
`- measures
     -- total count`

this is the hierarchy

`-- product_sales
   - product type
   - branch`


`-- salesgroup
   - group_name
   - group_leader
   - salesperson`

when i try to view it to the cube browser it only display salesperson with current sales.
but i want it to display zero if he/she doesnt have sales.

this is the current output:

             `total count
Group 1
     sp 1          1
     sp 2          2`

this is my desired output:

             `total count
Group 1
     sp 1          1
     sp 2          2
     sp 3          0`

Answer (score 0):

Cube Browser by default issues then `NON EMPTY` MDX clause for rows and columns.

To change this behavior, right click into any cell, select "Commands and Options"/"Report", and then check "Empty rows" and/or "Empty columns" below "Always show".